# isDisplayable(),isShowing(),isVisible() giving wrong values for JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, look-and-feel

**Env:**

OS: Win 10

IDE: Netbeans 8.1

Java: JDK 1.8u112 Oracle

jre: 10.0.2

JTattoo laf: HiFiLookAndFeel from http://www.jtattoo.net/

**Context:**

Creating a Look And Feel ("laf") switching class.

**Desc:**

There is a class A ("A") that extends JFrame("frame"). It has some GUI components like a JFileChooser("fc"), buttons etc. Its main("main") method comprises of making (inside the EDT via `Swingutilities.invokeLater()`("swingU")) an instace of A, setting A visible then invoking a doClick on a button(placed in the frame) that calls `fc.showOpenDilaog(this)`. At this point a frame and fc are visible on screen.

Coming back to the main. swingU returns to main. A delay of ~3 seconds is cretaed(see code) then the laf change is caused.

laf change is caused via another class called changer. It has a method called change, that

1. obtains all open windows via `Window.getWindows()`
2. sorts them into Jframes, JDialogs("dialog") and remaining into Windows by checking if their class has JFrame or JDialog as a superclass.
3. For each dialog records its visibility,sets a titlebar, disposes it, updates its UI then restores it as per its original visibility(see code)(not related but code also does the same for the frames)

The above steps themselves are exeecuted on the EDT via swingU.

**Problem:**

1. The laf change causes fc to disappear while A stays visible with the new laf.

**Expected:**

1. both fc and A should stay visible exhibiting the new laf.

**Headway into the problem:**

1. Used `System.out.println`("sop")(inside change method) to show the
   dialog's isDisplayable(),isShowing(),isVisible(). All of these
   returned false inspite of the fact that fc was clearly visible. After loooking into their source("src"), used the
   dialog.getParent()(this returned A) and soped its
   isDisplayable(),isShowing(),isVisible().These returned true. Doesn't make sense!
2. fc.showOpenDilaog(null) makes the problem disappear.
3. Even tried to look through sun.awt.AppContext--could't make heads or tails.

**Catch:**

1. The changer class can't access the memebers of A e.g. fc is private in A so is button...for all intents an purposes changer doesn't know the identitiy of the frame/dialog its analyzing.
2. The only thing special about the given configuration of lafs(from WindowsLookAndFeel to HiFiLookAndFeel) is that the later returns true for `getSupportsWindowDecorations()`

**Upon Andrew's advice, the SSCE**

```
    import com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel;
    import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Window;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.swing.JDialog;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JRootPane;
    import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class A extends javax.swing.JFrame {



public A() 
{
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jFileChooser1 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
    button = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button.setText("jButton1");
    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(128, 128, 128)
            .addComponent(button)
            .addContainerGap(195, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(71, 71, 71)
            .addComponent(button)
            .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
 jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
    //jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null) has no problem

}                                      


public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {



    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new HiFiLookAndFeel());

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            A x = new A();
            x.setVisible(true);

            x.button.doClick();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});



    Thread.sleep(3000);

changer.change(new WindowsLookAndFeel());
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton button;
private javax.swing.JFileChooser jFileChooser1;
// End of variables declaration                   

}


    class changer {

       public static void change(LookAndFeel laf) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {

           UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);

           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

               public void run() {

                   ArrayList<JFrame> frames = new ArrayList<>();
                   ArrayList<JDialog> dialogs = new ArrayList<>();
                   ArrayList<Window> winds = new ArrayList<>();

                   Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();

                   if (wins == null || wins.length == 0) {
                       return;
                   }

                   for (int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {

                       Class cls = wins[i].getClass();
                       if (JFrame.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
                           frames.add((JFrame) wins[i]);

                       } else if (JDialog.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
                           dialogs.add((JDialog) wins[i]);

                       } else {
                           winds.add(wins[i]);

                       }

                   }

                   boolean initialState = false;

                   if (frames.size() > 0) {

                       for (JFrame fr : frames) {
                           fr.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
                           initialState = fr.isVisible();

                           fr.dispose();
                           fr.setUndecorated(false);
                           SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(fr);
                           fr.pack();
                           fr.setVisible(initialState);
                       }
                   }

                   if (dialogs.size() > 0) {

                       for (JDialog dia :dialogs) {

                           dia.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
                           Container par = dia.getParent();
                           sop("par----");
                           sop(par);
                           sop("disp:" + par.isDisplayable());
                           sop("vis:" + par.isVisible());
                           sop("show:" + par.isShowing());
                           sop("dia----");
                           sop("disp:" + dia.isDisplayable());
                           sop("vis:" + dia.isVisible());
                           sop("show:" + dia.isShowing());

                           initialState = dia.isVisible();
                           dia.dispose();
                           dia.setUndecorated(false);
                           SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(dia);
                           dia.pack();
                           dia.setVisible(initialState);

                       }
                   }

               }
           });

       }

       public static void sop(Object obj)
       {
           System.out.println(obj);
       }

   }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).